# 'Mainmenu' does not name a type

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on car sharing project. So, I've done login and registration, after login the main menu is opening. In main menu I need to output a balance of an account. I do like this:

mainwindow.h

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <string>
#include <QDebug>
#include "mainmenu.h"
using namespace std;
class RegData;
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    RegData& givedata(); // the object of class from which I will get balance and output it in main menu
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private slots:
    void on_button_reg_clicked();

    void on_button_log_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Mainmenu *second; // the error is in this line
};
class RegData
{
private:
    QString login;
    QString email;
    QString password;
    int balance;
public:
    RegData(QString log = "", QString mail = "", QString pass = "", int bal=0) : login(log), email(mail), password(pass), balance(bal)
    {
    }
    void output()
    {
        qDebug() << login<<email<<password<<balance;
    }
    QString getLogin()
    {
        return login;
    }
    QString getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }
    QString getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }
    int getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    void setLogin(QString log)
    {
        login = log;
    }
    void setEmail(QString mail)
    {
        email = mail;
    }
    void setPassword(QString pass)
    {
        password = pass;
    }
    void setBalance(int balanc)
    {
        balance = balanc;
    }
};
```

Ok, how I did registration:

1. Receiving data from file into QVector data;
2. Receiving data from login/pass lines etc.
3. If login hasn't registered yet, put the data into file

So, there are a part of code in login system. The part checks is account registered, if it is, do something. In my case I change 'givedata()' values

```
for(QVector<RegData>::iterator it = data.begin(); it<data.end(); it++)
            {
                if(loginline == it->getLogin() && passwordline == it->getPassword() || loginline == it->getEmail() && passwordline == it->getPassword())
                {
                    islog = true;
                    givedata().setLogin(loginline);
                    givedata().setEmail(it->getEmail());
                    givedata().setPassword(passwordline);
                    givedata().setBalance(it->getBalance());
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    islog = false;
                }
            }
```

but I have an error

> C:\Users\david\Documents\Carsharring_files\mainwindow.h:33: ошибка: 'Mainmenu' does not name a type
> Mainmenu *second;
> ^

What is the line for? This is for main menu window object
I need to do some things with 'givedata()' in another window, there is why I do it

mainmenu.h is included

```
#ifndef MAINMENU_H
#define MAINMENU_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include "addmoney.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class Mainmenu;
}

class Mainmenu : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Mainmenu(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Mainmenu();

private slots:
    void on_plus_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Mainmenu *ui;
};

#endif // MAINMENU_H
```

I changed nothing in mainmenu.h, but includes

Comment: The error is telling you that it doesn't recognize the type `Mainmenu`. Is that a class that you have defined somewhere? If so, you need to include the header.

Comment: `mainmenu.h is included` not in the code you have shown us. Anyway how do you expect anyone to solve this problem without seeing mainmenu.h. The error could easily be in that file. But for some reason you haven't posted it.

Comment: mainmenu.h is simple header file, I changed nothing there

Comment: All the code after `Mainmenu *second; // the error is in this line` is clearly irrelevant, it is the code before that line (including the included files) that is important.

Comment: No, check one more time, I did it because there are 5 includes, not for taking a place

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `namespace Ui { class Mainmenu; }` says that there is a class named `Mainmenu` defined in the namespace `Ui`. `class Mainmenu : public QDialog { ... };` defines a class named `Mainmenu` in the global namespace. Those are two different classes, despite having the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You have a cyclic dependency of header files.

mainmenu,h includes mainwindow.h

mainwindow.h includes mainmenu.h

That's trouble (and note that couldn't be determined without seeing both header files).

Comment: How do you know what he is including in mainwindow.h?

Comment: @JarMan He doesn't show it, but he claims in the text of the question that is the case.

Comment: @JarMan Now it's shown in the code.

Comment: And what should I do? mainmenu.h in mainwindow.h is for launching main menu window and mainwindow.h in mainmenu.h is for 'givedata()'

Comment: @Nedaxses You have to break the cycle somehow. Forward declaration of classes is the usual way. Moving methods from the header file to a cpp file also helps.

Comment: @Nedaxses I see no reason that mainwindow.h has to include mainmenu.h, just forward declare the `Mainmenu` class. And I see no reason at all that mainmenu .h is including mainwindow.h. Just delete that #include.

Comment: @Nedaxses As far as I can see the `givedata` code is not in a header file, so make the includes you need in the cpp file, not in the header file.